# mysql update query wont execute

Tags: php

i have two update queries to update mysql db of the system.problem is my second update query works but my first one doesn't execute at all.
cant figure out whats going on...any help would be great
here is my php code.

```
$dob = $_POST["dob"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$mob = $_POST["mobileNo"];
$home = $_POST["homeNO"];
$files = $_FILES["filep"]["name"];

echo $files;
$folder = "images/";

$uid = $_SESSION["Uid"];


if($_FILES["filep"]["error"] == 4) {
    echo "no file selected";
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filep"]["tmp_name"] , "$folder".$_FILES["filep"]["name"]);


$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE User SET  DOB = '" . $uid . "', MOBNO = '" . $mob . "', HOMENO = '" . $home . "',DOB = '" . $dob . "',IMAGE_URL = '" . $files . "'   WHERE UID='" . $uid . "'");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE User_Credentials SET  NAME = '" . $name . "' WHERE CID='" . $uid . "'");
```

i have checked all the $name,$mob etc variables and value are passing without any problem..

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Austere me: There should be a severe penalty for anyone asking questions that show a clear lack of knowledge about SQL injection. Nicer me: Well, everybody has to learn, I am **sure** they'll change it the moment they realize what they did wrong.

Comment: @KIKO Software: people dont start learning basic php/mysql interaction with mysql injection. And in general barely anyone writes raw queries with unprocessed inputs these days anyway (all hail ORM).

Comment: @JayBlanchard nothing on the error log too

Comment: @Akalanka: add echo mysqli_error() after your queries to see what is wrong. See `https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php`

Comment: @Auris Yeah, I know, it's just that we see this so many times on Stack Overflow. Why not learn to do it right from the start? It's not like it is alright, when you start to learn to drive, to do it backwards, because once you've learned that, you can probably do it forwards too...

Comment: which data type are the columns involved  in update  ??

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but don't offput a person with penalties (even as joke, remeber when u were still learning), consired putting an actual answer explaining what he is doing wrong or at least a link to one of the milion articles that cover sql injection

Comment: @Auris My nicer self completely agrees with you. :-) And yes, you're right, it was a bit of a joke, but born out of frustration. Let's hope most people are indeed using ORM's for production.

Comment: @scaisEdge IMAGE_URL and LANG are varchar , DOB is date and other are int

Comment: In the first query you're assigning to the DOB column twice... What's your primary key? Should it be UID instead of DOB in the first case?